# HTML Imagemaps regular VS CSS Based

Tags: html, css, imagemap

I found that CSS Based HTML Imagemaps allow you get do neat things like set the style of the hot spots based on: hover, click, visited, etc. But you are limited to use squares & rectangles.

However I do not believe that you can do this in the standard html image maps.
But the benefit of standard html image maps are that you can polygons, circles.

**Is that limitation true?**

Sample CSS Based Image Map Code

```
<div class="imgmap_css_container" id="SeatingChartMap"><a style="position: absolute; `top: 396px; left: 565px; width: 20px; height: 43px;"  alt="A: 1: 1" title="A: 1: 1" href="11" target="" ><em>A: 1: 1</em></a><a style="position: absolute; top: 395px; left: 541px; width: 19px; height: 45px;"  alt="A: 1: 2" title="A: 1: 2" href="12" target="" ><em>A: 1: 2</em></a><a style="position: absolute; top: 392px; left: 516px; width: 21px; height: 47px;"  alt="A: 1: 3" title="A: 1: 3" href="13" target="" ><em>A: 1: 3</em></a><a style="position: absolute; top: 392px; left: 492px; width: 22px; height: 47px;"  alt="A: 1: 4" title="A: 1: 4" href="14" target="" ><em>A: 1: 4</em></a><a style="position: absolute; top: 390px; left: 469px; width: 20px; height: 48px;"  alt="A: 1: 5" title="A: 1: 5" href="15" target="" ><em>A: 1: 5</em></a><a style="position: absolute; top: 387px; left: 442px; width: 24px; height: 48px;"  alt="A: 1: 6" title="A: 1: 6" href="16" target="" ><em>A: 1: 6</em></a></div>`
```

Sample Standard HTML Image Map Code

```
<img src="rexall_place-seating-chart1561-791.gif" USEMAP="#NotNamed" BORDER=0>
<map name="NotNamed">
  <area shape="poly" coords="346,93,339,155,355,158,375,92,347,92" href="2"  alt="" title="">
  <area shape="rect" coords="305,95,332,152" href="1"  alt="" title="">
  <area shape="rect" coords="201,92,234,153" href="433"  alt="" title="">
  <area shape="rect" coords="237,92,266,154" href="4343"  alt="" title="">
  <area shape="rect" coords="272,91,300,154" href="32"  alt="" title="">
  <area shape="rect" coords="186,317,226,373" href="221"  alt="" title="">
  <area shape="rect" coords="183,443,212,477" href="11"  alt="" title="">
  <area shape="circle" coords="107,271,42" href="32"  alt="" title="">
  <area shape="poly" coords="361,230,367,241,424,239,410,202,360,229" href="2"  alt="" title="">
  <area shape="poly" coords="30,176,21,209,18,248,20,282,64,280,62,253,72,228,83,199,31,172" href="2"  alt="" title="">
</map>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative to maphilight is Image Mapster: http://www.outsharked.com/imagemapster/ I'm the author of this plugin, in full disclosure. It adds a substantial number of capabilities compared to maphilight (on which it was initially based).

Comment: Hi jamietre, can you contact me? aron (at) simpletick (dot) com
thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I do not believe that you could do non-square link hotspots using CSS, however, you could watch where someone clicks on the image using Javascript and have something fire or go to a url based on where the click was registered.  Or maybe using HTML5 canvas you could register some odd shaped hotspots?

Answer (score 0):

I confirmed:
CSS Based Image Maps

## They do not support ovals, circles, polygons

Standard Image Maps:

## They do support rectangles, ovals, circles, polygons

If you choose **Standard Image Maps** you can use this jquery plug-in to have control over hover and fill colors and borders, etc.
http://davidlynch.org/js/maphilight/docs/#defaults

Answer (score 0):

You can make circles, ovals, and a few irregular polygons by abusing the border-radius property.  Here's a circle:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Test Document</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        #link {
            width: 100px;
            height: 100px;
            -moz-border-radius: 50px 50px 50px 50px;
            -webkit-border-radius: 50px 50px 50px 50px;
            border-radius: 50px 50px 50px 50px;
            background: blue;
            display: block;
            text-indent: -999em;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Test Document</h1>

<a href="http://google.com/" id="link">Google</a>


</body>
</html>
```

This is not what border-radius is intended for, but it works in most modern browsers (but not in older IEs, like IE 8 and lower).

For more info, see: http://www.css3.info/preview/rounded-border/